# Unable to assign values to a parameter using Custom Distribution in Anylogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have an agent **Container** which has a parameter *carrier*; carrier can have two values *Truck* or *Train* which I have assigned using an option list. I have created an instance of Container in Main which is a population of 10 containers. I've created a custom distribution to assign values(Truck/Train) to *carrier* where no. of observations for Truck is 30 & for Train is 70.

When I run the model, I can see only a single value for carrier(Train). I want to have 10 values where Truck-Train will be in a ratio of 30-70. How can I do that? A snapshot of the properties of agent and carrier distribution is attached below.

Thank you in advance.

[carrierDistribution properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYRKa.png)
[container-agent properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hl6e.png)

Comment: I tried replicating your model and it seems to work fine... Feel free to share the model.

Comment: @EmileZankoul Thank you so much for your reply. I figured it out now, I guess I wasn't looking at the right place for parameter values. I am new to Anylogic.

Comment: @ChhandoseeBhattacharya do share your solution below so future users can learn from your mistake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I wasn't looking at the right place for the parameter values. So, I have an instance of my agent *Container* in *Main* which is a population of 10 agents. When I run the model and go to developer pannel, there will be agent numbers(0-9). When I scrolled through each agent, I could see different values for my parameter *carrier*.